# Index list recursion

Tags: python, function, recursion, indexing

I need help with this school assignment.

I need to write a function in Python called `ind(e, L)`; where the e is displayed for the first in L. I cannot use the index function.

So, for example:

`In [1]: ind(42, [55, 77, 42, 12, 42, 100])`
`Out[1]: 2`

or

`In [1]: ind('hi', ['oh', 'hi', 'there'])`
`Out[1]: 1`

**Edit**: Sorry I am also quite new to Stackoverflow.com, so sorry for not providing the code I already have so far.

This is my code, I have so far:

```
def ind(e, L):
    
    if L == '' or L == []:
        return 0
    else:
        return ind(L[0:]) + 1

assert ind(42, [20, 42, 60, 30]) == 2
```

Somehow my code doesn't seem to work.

I am very new to recursion and I think it still pretty hard to manage.
Can someone please help me with this code and explain in plain-English how the code works?

Your help will be MUCH appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. It's better now, but still not clear enough. What does "my code doesn't seem to work" mean? Why do you think it isn't working? Can you provide sample inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs? Or error messages?

Answer (score -1):

```py
def ind(e, L):
    for i, v in enumerate(L):
        # Iterates over [(0, 55), (1,77), (2,42)]
        if v == e:
            # If our current element matches the search, return the index
            return i
    # If none was found, return -1
    return -1
```

No recursion needed

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)

Comment: This is why some people make angry memes about Stack Overflow: OP is asking for recursion, the answer says "No recursion needed" :(

Comment: @ForceBru There's 'Don't do that, do this' and then there's 'I can't see how recursion would help here because you haven't provided any code'

Comment: @JammyDodger, I think the "because you haven't provided any code" part is completely irrelevant because the usage of recursion doesn't depend on whether the OP provided any code or not. However, the "I can't see how recursion would help here" part is the exact same as "Don't do that, do this", especially in this case where recursion _can_ help

Answer (score -1):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/list-comprehensions-no-python).

```
def ind(e, L):
    return  [k for k, i in enumerate(L) if i == e]
```